# base64 to binary conversion online gives different output than using the base64 module

Tags: python, python-3.x

ok so i converted a file to base64 on [this](https://www.browserling.com/tools/file-to-base64)  site.Then converted it to binary [here](https://conv.darkbyte.ru/)
did a quick check and the length  of the binary data was 6291456 from a 4mb file
i reversed the process and got my file back no problem

then tried the same thing in python using this code

```
import base64
import binascii
import codecs
from tkinter import filedialog
file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
    image_read =f.read()
    image_64_encode =base64.b64encode(image_read)

print(len(bin(int.from_bytes(str(image_64_encode).encode(), 
  'big')).replace('b','')))
```

the length returned 45226712
which seems to have greatly magnified the data
funny thing is the base 64 value of *image_64_encode* is exactly the same as on the site.
i'm relatively new to python  and dont for the life of me know what im doing wrong

Comment: Why aren't you using `base64.b64decode` for the decoding step?

Comment: yes i tried it too but it just gives me the contents of the file back like 'xe2\xda\x86\xa3\x97' but i would love to get the binary sequence of 1s and 0s without it been so different and larger than the output i get from the site

Comment: worked it out ,turns out i had a padding problem . it now gives me the exact length of bits